# Bot Framework: How to edit BOT messages using middleware

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to understand if it is possible to edit (i.e. convert .ToUpper()) all messages that are outgoing from the bot, using Middleware in bot framework?

I've tried to do it but I can see that IMiddleware Interface has defined only OnTurnAsync Task, which is triggered only when we got conversation update (i.e user join) or when we receive message from the user.

But how to catch the message that is sent by the bot (whether if its prompt or SendActivityAsync)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot) shows how to use middleware to catch messages send between bot and user